# JSONP and Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, instagram-api, html-framework-7

I'm trying to get images from Instagram public api via ajax and JSONP:

```
var target = https://www.instagram.com/p/BP3Wu_EDXsjdT5Llz13jFv2UeS0Vw0OTxrztmo0/?__a=1?callback=?';    

$$.ajax({                 
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  crossDomain: true,
                  url: target,

                  success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                  },                  

                error: function(xhr,status){
                    console.log("Error"+status);
                }
            });
```

I'm getting: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*.

What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: you're missing an opening quote on your target for one

Comment: that url doesn't return jsonp....open it in browser address bar yourself

Comment: First, your url is missing the opening `'`. And it should be `&callback` instead of `?callback`. But regardless, it looks like the public api doesn't support jsonp. Do you have any documentation showing that it does?

Answer (score 1):

A few mistakes...

```
var target = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BP3Wu_EDXsjdT5Llz13jFv2UeS0Vw0OTxrztmo0/?__a=1&callback=';
```

Changes: Missing ' at the beginning and changed second ? with &

Should work fine

Comment: The error recieved indicates that this is ***very*** unlikely to be the cause. well, the first change anyway.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry for helping?! I tried to write a comment but i cant?? Why!? Answers but no comments... sorry

Comment: No, you're doing all you can as a user with not enough rep to comment.

Comment: @KevinB Yes :/ Only 2 rep left :)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for helping...  but now, i get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: @PedroAntônio at wich line?

Comment: @howtoweb, the error appears in console... It considers ":" character of json as an error....

Comment: Right, which means instagram supports JSON, but not JSONP. the answer is.... you're out of luck.

Comment: Not very encouraging...rsrsrs... Any way to get the values via ajax?

Comment: @PedroAntônio Only JavaScript or with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

That API with `?__a=1` is undocumented API and does not support JSONP, so you cannot make client side API call using AJAX, you have to make a server side http request and it will work.

Comment: Hmmm... right... really is undocumented ... I'll work with server side so... Thanks :)